# MongoDB, collection name appears to be wrong

Tags: mongodb, schema, mern

When I try to call this request

```
const presidentModel = require('./modules/president.js')

app.get('/president', (req, res) => {
    presidentModel.find({}, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err) 
        } {
            console.log(result)
        }
    })
})
```

It only returns an empty array []
then it creates a new collection with the name 'presidents'

[image]

Here is my Schema

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose")

const presidentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nickname: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },

    fullname: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    },

    votes: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})
const president = mongoose.model("president", presidentSchema)
module.exports = president
```

The request should return the data on collection "president" but what it does is it creates a new collection with the name "presidents". I don't know where is it coming from tho

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is good practice to have your collections as plural, and therefore mongoose implicitly tries to make collections plural (as there are multiple items to be stored in them).

To override this, you can pass a third parameter to `.model()` with the name of the collection:

```js
const president = mongoose.model("president", presidentSchema, "president")
```